# file.isDirectory() returning false for directory

Tags: listview

I am trying to display images stored in 'Pictures' directory as a listView. In the MainActivity, I have created the variables as follows:

```
  //declare variables required for ListView
   private String[] FilePathStrings; //holds file path of the images captured.
   private String[] FileNameStrings;  //holds name of the images captured.
   private File[] listImage;    //holds the images.
   ListView list;
   ListViewAdapter adapter;
   File file;
```

Then in onCreate Method, I am calling populateListArray() to populate String and File arrays.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Populate the list array with image and file name
    populateListArray();

    //create ListAdapter and bind it to ListView
    createListAdapter();

}
```

and the PopulateListArray() is as follows:

```
   void populateListArray(){

    // Check whether SD Card exists
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Pictures");  //'Pictures' is the folder where google cam
                                                  // stores pictures.
        Log.i(MYTAG, "file = " +file); // file = /storage/sdcard0/Pictures
        Log.i(MYTAG, "file.isDirectory = " +file.isDirectory()); // file.isDirectory() is always returning false
    }


    //If 'Pictures' directory exists then populate the corresponding arrays

    if (file.isDirectory())   // following code is never executed as file.isDirectory() is always false.
    {
        listImage = file.listFiles();
        Log.i(MYTAG, "listImage = " +listImage);
        // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
        FilePathStrings = new String[listImage.length];

        Log.i(MYTAG, "FilePathStrings = " +listImage.length);
        // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
        FileNameStrings = new String[listImage.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < listImage.length; i++) {
            // Get the path of the image file
            FilePathStrings[i] = listImage[i].getAbsolutePath();
            // Get the name image file
            FileNameStrings[i] = listImage[i].getName();
        }
    } //endif

}
```

Following is the debug code generated:

```
07-24 23:07:30.417  26364-26364/com.example.lib.dailyselfie I/Lab-Selfie﹕ file = /storage/sdcard0/Pictures
07-24 23:07:30.417  26364-26364/com.example.lib.dailyselfie I/Lab-Selfie﹕ file.isDirectory = false
07-24 23:07:30.587  26364-26364/com.example.lib.dailyselfie D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
07-24 23:07:30.647  26364-26364/com.example.lib.dailyselfie D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
07-24 23:07:30.657  26364-26364/com.example.lib.dailyselfie D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
```

I don't understand why file.isDirectory() is returning 'false' in spite of 'Pictures' being a directory? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the required permissions to access the 'Pictures' directory.
Add the following to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```